# Html link onclick, jquery function, redirectToAction IIS server doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am struggling to use my submenus after publishing to IIS server.
For some reason the first redirect works properly, it gives me a 302 found. Then when it attempts to redirect to action and return a partialview it gives me a 500 internal server error code.

I am trying to update a partialview inside another partial view. This code works locally in a VS environment, but when I push it to a IIS Server it doesnt work.

I have tried searching for quite some time but cannot find anything that works. I am fairly new to MVC and IIS.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul id="submenu">
        <li><a class="LinkPart" href="#" onclick="getPartial(1);">Some subpage</a></li>
        <li><a class="LinkPart" href="#" onclick="getPartial(2);">Some subpage</a></li>
        <li><a class="LinkPart" href="#" onclick="getPartial(3);">Some subpage</a></li>
        <li><a class="LinkPart" href="#" onclick="getPartial(4);">Some subpage</a></li>
        <li><a class="LinkPart" href="#" onclick="getPartial(5);">Some subpage</a></li>
        <li><a class="LinkPart" href="#" onclick="getPartial(6);">Some subpage</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="right-box">
    <div id="right-box" class="data" style="visibility:visible;">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Admin/_AdminPartial.cshtml")
    </div>

</div>
```

Javascript at the bottom of the cshtml

```
function getPartial(y) {
    $.get(location.href = '@Url.Action("_PartialPickAdminpage", "Admin")/' + y, function (data) {
        $('div#right-box.data').html(data);
    })
}
```

and my Controller looks like this, with an example of one of the actions:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult _PartialPickAdminpage ( string id )
    {
        int newid = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        Debug.WriteLine("id partialpickAdminpage: " + id);
        if (newid.Equals(1))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account");
        }
        else if (newid.Equals(2))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("_SomePagePartial");
        }
        else if (newid.Equals(3))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("_SomePagePartial");
        }
        else if (newid.Equals(4))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("_SomePagePartial");
        }
        else if (newid.Equals(5))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("_SomePagePartial");
        }
        else if (newid.Equals(6))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("_SomepagePartial");
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Account/_ChangePasswordPartial.cshtml");
        }
    }

[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public PartialViewResult _SomePagePartial()
{
    TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "";
    return PartialView("~/Views/Admin/_SomePagePartial.cshtml");
}
```

One of the things I have noticed is that whenever I click one of the links it runs the _PartialPickAdminpage call twice locally, but only once and times out on IIS.

Found this in the logfile on the server.

```
    2016-12-19 10:46:53 192.168.0.145 GET /playlist - 80 nasoon 192.168.0.137 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 62
    2016-12-19 10:46:53 192.168.0.145 GET /Playlist/Views/StyleSheet.css - 80 nasoon 192.168.0.137 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36 http://to-be-more/playlist 404 0 0 0
    2016-12-19 10:46:53 192.168.0.145 GET /Playlist/Views/StyleSheet.css - 80 nasoon 192.168.0.137 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36 http://to-be-more/playlist 404 0 0 15
    2016-12-19 10:47:00 192.168.0.145 GET /Playlist/Admin/AdminSection - 80 nasoon 192.168.0.137 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36 http://to-be-more/playlist 200 0 0 46
    2016-12-19 10:47:10 192.168.0.145 GET /Playlist/Admin/_PartialPickAdminpage/1 - 80 nasoon 192.168.0.137 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36 http://to-be-more/Playlist/Admin/AdminSection 302 0 0 0
    2016-12-19 10:47:10 192.168.0.145 GET /Playlist/Admin/_PartialPickAdminpage/1 - 80 nasoon 192.168.0.137 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36 http://to-be-more/Playlist/Admin/AdminSection 302 0 0 203
2016-12-19 10:47:40 192.168.0.145 GET /Playlist/Account/Register - 80 nasoon 192.168.0.137 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36 http://to-be-more/Playlist/Admin/AdminSection 500 0 0 30150
2016-12-19 10:48:10 192.168.0.145 GET /Playlist/Account/Register - 80 nasoon 192.168.0.137 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36 http://to-be-more/Playlist/Admin/AdminSection 500 0 0 40306
```

The Account controller with the Register action:

```
        [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        UserRepository ur = new UserRepository();
        var list = ur.MyListTable();
        var model = new RegisterModel();
        model.DropDownList = new SelectList(list, "RoleID", "RoleName");
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Connection string to database, starred out user and password:

```
Data Source=TO-BE-MORE\SQL2016;Initial Catalog=tbmplaylist;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130951/discussion-on-question-by-nasoon-html-link-onclick-jquery-function-redirecttoa).

Comment: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString; . this willr ead the connection string from webconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The database connectivity was not happening initially so 500 internal error.[timeout execption] Some functions used local connectionstrings (ADO.net). Use two connection strings in web.config, one for EF and one for ADO.net.

```
<add name="Database1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Database1Entities1.csdl|res://*/Models.Database1Entities1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Database1Entities1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=TO-BE-MORE\SQL2016;initial catalog=tbmplaylist;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User ID=****;Password=****;Connection Timeout=120;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
<add name="Database1EntitiesADO" connectionString="Data Source=TO-BE-MORE\SQL2016;initial catalog=tbmplaylist;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User ID=***;Password=****;Connection Timeout=120;App=EntityFramework"/>
```

Then in methods call like this:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database1EntitiesADO"].ConnectionString
```

2) The action which is called will return an actionresult . So wont be getting partial result.

3) Redirecttoaction creates a new request so the initial query will first get executed and then end_request will be called then new_request is created that is the reason for twice execution.

Changing the jquery scripts to look like this fixed issues 2 and 3:

```
        function getPartial(y) {
        $.get('_PartialPickAdminpage/' + y, function (data) {
            $('div#right-box.data').html(data);
        })
   }
```